# C# and Sqlite field length

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have made a table in SQLite and choosed varchar(30) for one Field but it seems as i actually can save much longer strings, is this normal? Can anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's normal, and explained in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.

(Note that before seeing this question, I had no idea about this. It's always worth checking the documentation first.)

Comment: I see, thank you, i thought i needed longer Field than 30 chars and had to recreate my table but no need as i understand now, thanks again